# Can we ban questions on earth science in the help center?

Tags: feature-request, scope, help-center

This question is triggered by the recent '[Why is the soil so black on constuction site](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/why-is-the-soil-so-black-on-constuction-site)'.

Can we make it clear in the help center that this type of question is not a good fit to Gardening & Landscaping?

So far the [Help Center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) goes like this:

> #### and it's not about:
>
> - culinary uses of herbs/fruits/plants (try [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)),
> - health and nutritional aspects of fruits/vegetables (try [Fitness & nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)),
> - plant biology, beyond what is generally gardening knowledge (try [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)),
> - the framing, plumbing or electrical aspects of building greenhouses, decks, or other structures (try [Home improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)), or
> - large scale agriculture and/or the business of gardening,
>
> then you're in the right place and we'd love to help answer your question.

Can we add something like:

> - environmental science or the geological aspects of soil, land, etc. (try [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm good with suggesting that Earth Science questions are better in another Stack Exchange site.  As long as the distinction between soil science which is integral to good gardening and Earth Science is made.

Comment: I proposed using 'geological aspects of soil'. That should distinguish that from the soil science that we'd consider on-topic on GL.